# how do get members of an organisation from github api

Tags: curl, github

I am confused as to why my curl: `curl https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/members` is only returning an array of length 5, when there are over 50 people in the organisation?

when I do `curl https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/members?page=2`, it just returns `[    ]` indicating there are no more?

is this concept of people and members different from the website to the api?

or do I need to do something different to get all the members??

Comment: Are you a member of that organization? Are you authenticating your curl request?

Comment: yes I am a member, no authentication but surely if i needed to be authenticated, i wouldn't be able to see any of them??

Comment: You could give it a try by adding a "-u yourusername" into the curl command. I cant be able to test this right now.

Comment: @mofoe works! if you comment that as answer I can accept it

Comment: sorry, one last thing. how would you turn that curl into a get request?

Comment: as in I know how to do it but how would you add the `u username` stuff into a get request?

Comment: It should be a GET request by default if you did not include any other options. You can look at the request in more detail by adding a "-v".

Comment: sorry I mean I made an `axios.get()` request, where do I add the `u username` to that?

Comment: in javascript, react. not in curl/command line land anymore

Comment: See my answer below. Id recommend to use an OAuth2 token for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#members-list) states that:

```
If the authenticated user is also a member of this organization then both concealed and public members will be returned.
```

So you might need to be authenticated to list all the users in an organization.
You can do this with curl by adding the `-u` option:

```
curl -u "username:password" https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/members
```

In general I would recommend to use an OAuth2 token instead of Basic Auth in your scripts. You can read about the supported authentication schemes [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication).

Comment: sorry I'm still confused as to how to access the url with a username NOT using curl??

I've tried this:
`
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/:orgs/members',
      auth: {
        username: username,
        password: secret
      }
    });`

but I get a 401 unauthorised??